# Application insights showing a lot of dependency failures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, restsharp

I have application Insights in my project. I use rest sharp to access to a web API that has all the data access.

when I go to application insights failures, I do see a lot of dependency failures.
when I take a look at the failures are calls to the API but with no parameters.

Examples:

```
  /PALSOFTwebapi/PALSOFTapi/FrontDeskLog/Hospitals/
  /PALSOFTwebapi/PALSOFTapi/FrontDeskLog/EmployeeSameCompany/
```

those calls should have parameters and im getting http 404

do you have any idea why this is happening?
I have no clue why this is happening on my application.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

PS: Application is not affected in performance and is not throwing any error at all. I'm using nlog to log and im logging all errors and nothing is saved there. I just see that info in Azure.

I have debugged the application cant see anything.

Comment: Well, probably ppl are trying those urls. It is a public facing api? Did you inspect the details ,they might reveal the origin.

Comment: Hello @PeterBons , no it is not a public-facing API jaja. the details in azure don't tell me anything else. Thank you

Comment: Ok. And it are not requests marked as [synthetic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-context#synthetic-source-of-the-operation)? Best way is to query details is using log analytics, have you done that? App Insights does not add things by itself so the requests do originate from somewhere. Could even be a ping by a healthcheck service.

Comment: @PeterBons I will research more about the synthetic request. I have like 8 other applications deployed and none of them has that issue. I have an API to log usage and that API is being used in all the applications.  I have found another application that has some dependencies failures calling the application. 
It could be related to the fact that I'm calling the API inside a task function? Thank you for your help

Comment: *It could be related to the fact that I'm calling the API inside a task function?* Should not cause any issues, unless tasks are not properly awaited and causes exceptions to disappear..

Comment: @PeterBons will check that.. thank you so much

Comment: @SergioCabreraGari Please summarize your findings as an answer if you're not unblocked anymore so it benefits others in the community having similar queries. Thanks!

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT I haven't been able to resolve the issue yet. I have been working on other stuff. will post as soon as I have something. Thank you